# What is MAX(DISTINCT x) in SQL?

Tags: sql, jooq

I just stumbled over [jOOQ's maxDistinct SQL aggregation function](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.3.x/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#maxDistinct%28org.jooq.Field%29).

What does `MAX(DISTINCT x)` do different from just `MAX(x)` ?

Comment: I would guess that it's just there for consistency with the other aggregates for which distinct and non-distinct aggregation could produce different values.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: +1. I guess that would explain it on the SQL level. Keeps your BNF simple. But why would people include it in their hand-coded persistance library (where adding it is an extra effort).

Comment: @Thilo: Reasoning about exceptions is actually more work than just blindly following the BNF... Nice discovery, though ;-)

Answer (score 4):

`maxDistinct` and `minDistinct` were defined in order to keep consistency with the other aggregate functions where having a distinct option actually makes a difference (e.g., `countDistinct`, `sumDistinct`).

Since the maximum (or minimum) calculated between the distinct values of a dataset is mathematically equivalent with the simple maximum (or minimum) of the same set, these function are essentially redundant.

Answer (score 1):

In short, there will be no difference. In case of MySQL, it's even stated [in manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max):

> Returns the maximum value of expr. MAX() may take a string argument;
>   in such cases, it returns the maximum string value. See Section 8.5.3,
>   “How MySQL Uses Indexes”. The DISTINCT keyword can be used to find the
>   maximum of the distinct values of expr, however, this produces the
>   same result as omitting DISTINCT.

The reason why it's possible - is because to keep compatibility with other platforms. Internally, there will be *no difference* - MySQL will just omit influence of `DISTINCT`. It will not try to do something with set of rows (i.e. produce distinct set first). For indexed columns it will be `Select tables optimized away` (thus reading one value from index, not a table), for non-indexed - *full scan*.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not wrong there are no difference

For Columns

```
ID
1
2
2
3
3
4
5
5
```

The OUTPUT for both quires are same 5

```
MAX(DISTINCT x)

// ID = 1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5
// DISTINCT = 1,2,3,4,5
// MAX = 5 
// 1 row
```

and for

```
MAX(x)

// ID = 1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5
// MAX = 5
// 1 row
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, DISTINCT x ensures that every element is different from a certain set. The max operator selects the highest value from a set. In plain SQL there should be no difference between both.